# file path is not retrieved in codeigniter

Tags: file, codeigniter, filepath, email-attachments

I am creating an invoice on users desired package selection. The pdf file is being created (but it takes some time), while the code checks for the file. The file exists. Here is the address of the file;

```
C:/wamp/www/proposal/file/invoice/Basic_52_60.pdf
```

This is the correct path to the file. I am passing this path to the function in another controller as;

```
redirect('email/email_invoice/'.$file);
```

When I tested the file path in email_invoice function, it displayed only c:

```
c:
```

The slashes in the path are not transferred. I don't know exactly what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter considers each segment of the URL a parameter after the controller and method. So you are essentially passing 7 variables to the `Email::email_invoice()` method.

You could use some sort of encoding to pass it as one variable and then decode it on the other side such as:

```
 $file = base64_encode($file);
 redirect('email/email_invoice/' . $file);
```

Then in Email.php:

```
public function email_invoice($file) {
    $file = base64_decode($file);
}
```

Or you could pass it as a get parameter:

```
redirect('email/email_invoice/?file=' . $file);

public function email_invoice() {
    $file = $this->input->get('file');
}
```

The latter requires the $_GET array to be enabled which it is not by default.

**UPDATE - Using Flashdata**

Based on some of the comments I thought I would update this answer. `base64_encode()` can result in characters that will break the URL so you would need to use:

```
$file = urlencode(base64_encode($file));
redirect('email/email_invoice/' . $file);
```

And on the other side:

```
public function email_invoice($file) {
    $file = urldecode(base64_decode($file));
}
```

As the OP pointed out $_GET variables can be manipulated leaving you open to [directory traversal attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) or other vulnerabilities. Even if done right you would need extra code for security. Encoding can easily be spotted and altered.

File paths probably shouldn't be carried around in the URL. POST data can be manipulated also even if it is less obvious. Security through obscurity is not security at all. A better approach would be to use [flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('email_invoice_pdf', $file);
redirect('email/email_invoice/');
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function email_invoice() {
    $file = $this->session->flashdata('email_invoice_pdf');
}
```

That's it. The session was used to carry the file path to the next page request, but after that it is gone.

Comment: In 2.1.3+ `$_GET` access is enabled by default. It's CI's query string based URLs that are disabled initially.

Comment: `urlencode()` is another option for passing items through the URL that have slashes and other URI characters in it.

Comment: I tested urlencode and I keep getting errors so I went with base64_encode

Comment: Lol you're right, it gets interpreted as literal characters and has the same issue. Derp. It works great for query strings, though.

Comment: Hey Thank you J.Money. I tried the base64_encode() but it gave error that the url does not accept the encryption. But the get parameter worked brilliant. Thanks a lot. BTW is GET method of sending data safe? can we use POST method to achieve this?

Comment: POST would work just fine. Any solution that gets around CI's url structure would work. You could also look at [flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). GET is perfectly safe if you use it properly. Users can alter GET vars which means they could specify the file and perhaps attempt directory traversal so you would need security in place within `email_invoice()`.